# Automatically add app to Office365 "my apps" launcher

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory

We are developing a cloud-based application which requires users to sign in. There are multiple ways in which users may do so; one of the ways desired by some of our customers is to use Azure AD based single sign on.

We have achieved a basic functionality that allowes this by registering our application as a multi-tenant app in our Azure AD, and providing a method for a customer to give permission to our app to access their Azure AD.

When this has been done, users of this customer may login to our app by accessing the "login" URL of our app via a bookmark, a button, or something similar.

However, our customers would appreciate the app being visible in the Office365 "My Apps" listing.

This can be achieved by manual action of the customer's Azure AD admin, by adding each and every one of their users to the app. However, this is a somewhat tedious task to do for hundreds of users, and has to be done whenever a new user is added.

Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Kind regards,

Andreas Trottmann

Comment: No. The app shouldn't be able to hold any tenant permissions.

Comment: Is there a way to grant this permission? The action of granting "admin consent" (i.e. giving the app permission to access the AD) could be combined with an action of granting "add-to-the-launcher consent". In our experience, customers have been asking for this, so it is reasonable to assume that they would grant this permission.

Comment: Admin can assign an app to a group of users, then users will be able to see this app under My Apps section/link. Users have to pin certain apps to show in the app launcher. hope this helps. The app launcher is a personalized menu for o365 users were users pick what to show in it.